# Icon shows up in the simulator and not when I simulate it on the iPad

Tags: ipad

I have a 72X72 png picture called Icon.png in the Resources folder. It shows up nicely when I run the app on the Iphone Simulator but not when I run it on the iPad. The Icon is assigned in the -info.plist.
I tried Run and Clean, Run and Clean ALL. 
i get the following error:

```
Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007) iPad: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  You must define CFBundleIconFile, CFBundleIconFiles, or provide a default Icon.png that is 72x72 (-19013)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I spent 2 days. When you build and archive, click show in finder, show the contents of the package of the archive and check if all the files are showing up. For me, the archive was missing Icon.png file for some reason. The archive utility has a bug. I moved the icons out of the resource folder, cleaned and built the project. Then again I moved the icons into the resource folder and cleaned and built it. Then the archive had copied the missing icon files. So try this out!!